# RowFilter on JFace TreeViewer

Tags: jface, rcp, e4, rowfilter, treeviewer

I have a TreeViewer as shown here: 
[image: TreeViewer].

I have a text field to enter the percentage values. Suppose the percentage entered is 30 %, I should hide all the rows that are below 30% and display only the rows above 30%. Is there any row filter that I can use for my TreeViewer? It would be great if some examples are provided.

I am using e4 RCP. I want to do View based filtering and prefer not to change the Model.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You use a class which extends `ViewFilter` to filter the rows in a tree viewer.
The main method to override in the `ViewFilter` is the `select` method:

```java
@Override
public boolean select(Viewer viewer, Object parentElement, Object element)
```

here you are given the object being considered (`element`) along with its parent and the viewer. You return `true` to keep displaying the element and `false` to hide it.

You can have several filters active if required, set them in the tree viewer using:

```java
treeViewer.setFilters(array of view filters);
```

You may need to call

```java
treeViewer.filter();
```

when something changes in the tree which requires the filters to be re-run.

Comment: Yes that worked. I also have another issue, which I have described as separate question.[link] (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36745388/java-swt-how-can-i-make-only-one-column-editable-in-treeviewer-based-on-checkb/36750182#36750182). I need to select atleast one value from each group using the checkbox and only the corresponding row should become editable. Could you please suggest me how  to do it?